# I can not precompile my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, assets, precompile

I can not precompile with the command --> `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`  , It retuns me this error --> `Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'.`

Before to precompile I did a `bundle install --deployment --without development test`

Rails 3.0.11

Ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: There wasn't Asset Pipeline in Rails 3.0.x yet. This was introduced in Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You said you used bundle install to precompile, this does not precompile assets but simply installs your gems, if you want to install updated gems to the rails server simply run `bundle install` or `bundle update` again. There is no assets pipeline for rails 3.0.

If you did want to use the assets pipeline there is [this backport](https://github.com/jamesmacaulay/sprockets_rails3_backport), from the docs:

In your Gemfile:

```
gem "sprockets_rails3_backport"
...plus whatever supplementary gems you want for the asset pipeline:

gem 'coffee-script', '2.2.0'
gem 'therubyracer', '0.9.9'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
```

In your routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  if (app = Rails.application).config.assets.compile
    mount app.assets => app.config.assets.prefix
  end

  # ...
end
```

Here are the various config.assets options and their defaults:

```
config.assets.paths                    = []
config.assets.precompile               = [ Proc.new{ |path| !['.js', '.css'].include?(File.extname(path)) },
                                           /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/ ]
config.assets.prefix                   = "/assets"
config.assets.version                  = ''
config.assets.debug                    = false
config.assets.compile                  = true
config.assets.digest                   = false
config.assets.manifest                 = nil
config.assets.cache_store              = [ :file_store, "#{root}/tmp/cache/assets/" ]
config.assets.js_compressor            = nil
config.assets.css_compressor           = nil
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true
```